# AsyncTask not showing dialog during operation

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

The progressDialog of my AsyncTask not showing. It seems correct but it doesn't display the dialog.. The operations inside works perfectly but seems ignoring the `onPreExecute()` and `onPostExecute()` methods..

```
private class copyApk extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    int appPosition;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(Void pre) {
        super.onPreExecute();

        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Copy apk");
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Copying...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }



    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... apks) {
        final File customfolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+File.separator+"HazyApkBackup");
        if(!customfolder.exists()){
            customfolder.mkdirs();
        }
        try
        {

            vacca = getActivity().getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(app.getPackageName(), packageManager.GET_META_DATA).sourceDir.toString();
            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Boh "+vacca, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cp " + vacca + " " + customfolder);
            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Apk copied in "+customfolder, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException | IOException e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Sorry, the apk was not copied correctly", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }       

        return null;
        }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

        if(mProgressDialog.isShowing())
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Apk copied in "+customfolder, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();  

    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: how did you start the asynctask?

Comment: In this way: new copyApk().execute();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `onPreExecute()` method isn't getting called, as it has the incorrect signature. The correct method has no parameters.

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute()
{
    ...
```

Comment: Remove the `Void pre` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The prototype of `onPreExecute()` :

```
@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

}
```

The `onPreExecute()` and `onPostExecute()` methods are called on the UI thread. It is always better to use a `WeakReference` to avoid exceptions in future.

In your `AsyncTask`, create a `WeakReference` like :

```
private WeakReference<MyActivity> myWeakContext;
```

Then in your `onPreExecute()`,

```
MyActivity activity = this.myWeakContext.get();
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
```